# How do I convert a Node.js library into something that can be used in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I want to call this Node.js library from the browser:

```
cloudmersive-convert-api-client
```

The NPM page says that you can use browserify.  I tried using wzrd.in (hosted browserify) to generate a browser JS file:

https://wzrd.in/standalone/cloudmersive-convert-api-client@latest

However, wzrd.in which I am new to does not say how to actually call it.  When I write the following code:

```
var CloudmersiveBarcodeapiClient = require('cloudmersive-convert-api-client');
```

in an HTML page I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How do I actually import this library once I have converted it into Browser Javascript?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you could use ES6 module syntax - which works in modern browsers (and node) - but, not sure how that relates to the code produced by browserify - perhaps there's some documentation for browserify that explains how to use the output code in a browser - just read the instructions myself ... seems like you may not be adding the bundled js in a script tag in your html

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks - I read the browserify docs but it is confusing because it says to write your JS first, then to run browserify on your JS application (not on the source library).  Since wzrd.in does the library (not your code) that is how I got here.  What would ES6 module syntax look like in this case?  (I don't normally code in JS so that is part of my issue here)

Comment: ignore the ES6 module part of my comment - that won't help - edited the comment, so please re-read

Comment: Can you tell us the browsify command that you used for cloudmersive-convert-api-client.

Comment: @SaiKarthik I used this website for hosted browserify: https://wzrd.in/standalone/cloudmersive-convert-api-client@latest which has more details here:  https://wzrd.in/

Comment: require('cloudmersive-convert-api-client') This still won't work on your HTML. Because your browser still doesn't have implementation for require. Only the file you hosted cloudmersive-convert-api-client will have the implementation of require in a cloure and not for complete DOM. you should use script tag like this - <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/cloudmersive-convert-api-client@latest" /> in your html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of browserify is that it looks for `require()` calls, and provides the sort of stuff to make it work. In some cases starting with a `require` function.

Have you considered trying to use a bundle instead of just asking for a stand alone version of one module?

Bundle here: https://wzrd.in/bundle/cloudmersive-convert-api-client@latest

After loading a bundle I was able to run the sample code that does a `require`

`var CloudmersiveBarcodeapiClient = require('cloudmersive-convert-api-client');`